# Self-managed ElasticSearch : horizontal auto-scaling on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling, horizontal-scaling

Context:

i'm working on a highly availble faulty tolerent deployment of elasticsearch cluster for production envirnment, composed of 3 master nodes & 3 data nodes (as docker container) deployed on 3 ec2 instances 'master + data nodes on each ec2 instance'.(see architecture in attachment)

[image]

Situation:

till now the cluster is up and works perfectly but i'm still looking for a solution for auto-scaling, for example : if one of my cluster nodes stops working (Ec2 instance get down) i need to know how automatically provision new node and join it to existing cluster ?

Is AWS Auto-scaling group service will work for this situation ?
Do you have any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a solution using the AWS Auto-scaling group, but how about using [Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/index.html) as a control brain? ([blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-elastic-cloud-on-kubernetes-the-elasticsearch-operator-and-beyond))

They supports not only scaling up/down and maintaining the nodes, but also almost all the operations required (version management, configuration management, etc.).

> - Managing and monitoring multiple clusters
> - Upgrading to new stack versions with ease
> - Scaling cluster capacity up and down
> - Changing cluster configuration
> - Dynamically scaling local storage (includes Elastic Local Volume, a local storage driver)
> - Scheduling backups

Comment: Hi @pakio
I'm working on self-managed service not fully-managed (Elastic Cloud) and also we don't have a container orchestrator we are using only docker-compose on each ec2 instance.